# Declaring a Variable in PHP

Tags: php

I wrote a script a while back, but upon having some issues with it in the past few days, I noticed when reviewing it that I am not properly population a variable. What is the proper way to delcare a variable in PHP and populate it in a sub-scope? My current code looks as follows but I had problems with the $results var not being filled.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $GLOBALS["api_url"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = explode(";",$data);
$results = array();

foreach ($data AS $temp)
{
    $temp = explode("=",$temp);
    $results[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
}

if ($results["result"] == "success")
{
    $log_terminate_success = "Service ID #" . $serviceid . " has been Immediately Terminated Successfully!";
    log_activity($log_terminate_success);

    return true;
}
else
{
    $log_terminate_failure = "Service ID #" . $serviceid . " has failed Immediate Termination: " . $results["message"];
    log_activity($log_terminate_failure);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: In a comment below, you mentioned that `$data` could be `result=error&message=xxx`. Doesn't that mean your first explode should be on `&`, not `;`?

Comment: It also means you should use `parse_str` instead of parsing it manually.

Comment: I just updated the sample code to include the result checking. It seems the value of $data before exploding is "result=success;" then the first explode just removes the ; from the end. After that it should explode "result=success" into two parts and shouldn't everything read correctly? For some reason its not reading "$results["result"]" as "success" so I guess something is wrong with the explode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to declare variables in PHP.

If your `$results` aren't getting filled: You should test if `$data` is being filled correctly. Try using `print_r($data);` to see if there's the right data where you expect it to be.

Also, when you `foreach()` your data which is an array after you `explode()` it, `$temp` is no longer an array. You then explode it again into another array. You should also test if this data is what you expect it to be in case the original `$data` behaves as expected.

Comment: `$temp[0]` will be the first character of the string.

Comment: True, but the way he's trying to use it seems more like an array; since he explodes it right after again and tries to replace the first part with the second part.
Probably trying to filter out a URI or something.

Comment: 'sorry - I mis-read the original code. Inside the loop, he explodes it again, so it actually will be an array again.

Comment: That code is taken straight from the WHMCS API page. The results are either "result=success" or "result=error&message=xxx". They also had $result though so there may be other issues with their demo code.

Comment: Shouldn't matter. I would still check if `$data` is filled with the correct data after exploding it.

Comment: Okay thanks. I just found the original code I was basing it off of at http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Example_Usage Does that actually work though as there is no $results defined out of that scope, but maybe thats just another PHP thing

Comment: As I said @BrettPowell, PHP doesn't require you to define your variables, although it's considered a good thing to do so to prevent troubles in the future. 
However, you should test if your `$data` is filled and update your original post with that information in order for us to help you look for the actual problem. Maybe it's CURL which isn't installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results;
```

This surprisingly does absolutely nothing in PHP. You'd think it'd create the variable `$results` as empty, but in fact it doesn't even do that. You have to assign it a value:

```
$results = array();
```

Comment: You don't have to do this. It could be a good practice to make your code more clearer, but it's not preventing his code from working.

Comment: @Bjorn It's virtually required to do so! If the loop doesn't execute because `$data` is empty, the variable will not be declared at all and you'll try to access an undefined variable after the loop. That's a pretty basic and common pattern for problems.

Comment: No. I understand what you mean and I agree; as I said, it's good practice. But it's not preventing his code from running as he described. It's not the source of his problem and declaring his variable won't magically fix this.

Comment: If you run PHP with warnings and notices enabled (a good practice), you do need to do this - and you need to ensure the 'result' index is defined.

Comment: @Bjorn Alright. I found it worth pointing out though, as it's the title of the question and an obvious not-so-obvious problem. I agree there are more problems here though.

Comment: @jcsanyi I totally agree, which reminds me; my XDebug should be logging errors at a higher default level. But this still doesn't fix any of his problems. I'm a huge sucker for trying to teach newer folks some good practice, but we should do that after we help him debug his code. Else there's no way he'll ever get grib on learning to program well.

Comment: Thanks for all the help thus far guys. Generally this would be much easier but the person whose running my script (a co-worker) has US IP's blocked from his web-server and I am troubleshooting through logging only. It seems $data is returning "$result=success;" so I guess the problem is with the exploding but I can't see any issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, there's 2 things you need to ensure:

1. You're accessing the `$results` variable inside the loop as an array, so you need to make sure that it's an array.
2. After the loop, you're checking the `'result'` index - so you probably want that to always be defined.

You can do that by putting this line before your loop:

```
$results = array('result' => 'unknown');
```

This will define the variable as an array, and set the starting `result` value to the st ring '`unknown'`. That value will probably be overwritten inside the loop, but if it's not, you'll still have a valid comparison after the loop - you won't be referencing an undefined array index.

Answer (score -1):

you could try:

```
$results = array();

if( !empty($data) AND is_array($data) ) {
    foreach ($data AS $temp) {
        $temp = explode("=",$temp);
        $results[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? What is different from the original code, and why is this better?

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is here:

```
$data = explode(";",$data);
$results;
```

it should be:

```
$data = explode(";",$data);
$results = array();
```

Comment: Why? Giving random code changes to make with no explanation isn't really an answer.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Try it.